# Flipping an Excel spreadsheet to opposite axis programmatically

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet where the data is displayed in columns. For example:

[image]

I want to flip this spreadsheet so that the header cells are in Column A, and the data in Column B, C, and D. For example:

[image]

Is it possible to accomplish this through an Excel feature/programmatically? I'd rather not flip the data manually.

I am using Excel for Mac 2007, but a solution using any version would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Copy` `PasteSpecial, Transpose`

Comment: @chrisneilsen: Transpose worked perfectly. If you repost this as an answer, I will upvote and accept.

Comment: go ahead and accept your own answer.  glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the simplest method to accomplishing this is using the `Transpose` feature, as [suggested by chris neilsen in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810646/flipping-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-opposite-axis-programmatically#comment31202707_20810646).

Here are the steps to using `Transpose` using Office for Mac 2007:

> Copy/Cut the Data --> `Edit` --> `Paste Special...` --> `Transpose`

[image: Paste Special menu]

Comment: I didn't get your question, this is what I think you were calling "flip the data manually".

Comment: @RicardoOliveros-Ramos: Sorry for the confusing rhetoric. By "flip the data manually," I meant I did not want to copy each cell individually into a new spreadsheet. But thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This macro will create a new Sheet with the tranposed data:

```
Sub TransposeData()
'
' TransposeData Macro
'

'
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

You need to be at the left upper corner of the data and then run the macro.